# Show and hide spans inside parent div on click not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, angularjs

My markup looks like:

```
<div class="box" ng-click="listThis()" ng-show="isVisible">
 <span class="text">content ....</span>
 <span class="text2">content2 ....</span>
 <span class="text3">content3 ....</span>
```

My code looks like:

```
var spans = 2;
var i = 0;
$scope.newlist= [];

while (i < spans){
$scope.newlist.push(i+1);
i++;
}

$scope.listThis=function(){
$scope.isVisible=!$scope.isVisible;
}
```

However when I click on / off everything within class="box" is hidden and doesn't really take my spans value to limit, say, 2 spans are shown only.

Now sure if I've missed anything out, or a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you try to make a demonstration of your problem in a fiddle like https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Your question is not complete i guess. what you want to limit? Also u have missing </div> tags

Comment: I think you got a wrong idea on how this should work. Angular hides everything within the container you are hiding.

Comment: I think a better way to go would be to explain what you're trying to do, since your code doesn't really make any sense as it is right now.

Comment: I'm just trying to hide the number of span content tags. So I'd like to display 1, 2 or 3 depending on the var span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first answer is a good answer about your issue on ng-show.

According to your comments you may want to use a ng-repeat with a filter.

First here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/otzNkKGiXtT4IMAjjRg0?p=preview)

HTML :
The ng-repeat - `limit` is a $scope var. the "limitTo" filter return the n first elements of the list.

```
<div>
    <span ng-repeat="span in spans | limitTo: limit">{{span.content}}<br/></span>
</div>
```

JS :

```
//Now your span elements are objects with the attribute "content"
$scope.spans = [{content:"Test1"},{content:"Test2"},{content:"Test3"}]
```

You can bind an input to `limit` with `ng-model="limit"`. Or simply doing `$scope.limit = 2` in your JS

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your ng-show is on your div which contains the spans. So if `isVisible` is false, the entire div and all its content is hidden. To change this you should create conditions for each span, which show/hide accordingly.
For example:

```
<div class="box">
    <span class="text" ng-click="listContentOne()" ng-show="oneIsVisible"></span>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.listContentOne = function() {
    $scope.oneIsVisible = !$scope.oneIsVisible;
}
```

This is a very simple and basic version of what you want to achieve, but with this information you should be able to derive your own solution.

Comment: The only problem with this is, if you don't know how many spans you have in your content, say you add a fourth, a fifth, etc, unless you have the additional condition on each one, it's not going to work, right?

Comment: @Poiro You probably want to use ng-repeat then.

Comment: No but to be honest, your entire code didn't really make sense. You should think of rewriting it and think of a structure which makes your code a lot more flexible  (for example, use an object for each span containing the content and for example an ID property, and then use ng-repeat)

Answer (score 1):

An `ng-repeat` is probably more what you're looking for. Assuming you have dynamic content for your spans setup like so:

```
$scope.spans = [
  {content: 'content1'},
  {content: 'content2'},
  {content: 'content3'}
]
```

Then your html should be like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="span in spans">{{span.content}}</span>
```

From there you have a few options depending on what you want to do. If your spans are sorted and you just want to show a certain amount, add `$scope.limit` somewhere and use [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo):

```
<span ng-repeat="span in spans | limitTo: limit">{{span.content}}</span>
```

Otherwise put another variable on the span objects called `visible`, set that to true or false, and then do

```
<span ng-repeat="span in spans" ng-show="span.visible">{{span.content}}</span>
```